# Sidr menu trigger with another button

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, sidr, siteorigin

I am quite new at programming and have a serious question (for my level). I am using a sidr-plugin (gottent from this site: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-side-menus-to-a-wordpress-theme/ (the updated version at the bottom)), and I was wondering, if it is possible to use a simple SiteOrigin button widget on wordpress to duplicate for one of the sidr menus and open it ? This is what I use in my theme along with the plugin:

```js
<< ? php

function put_up_left() {
  echo ' <
    a href = "#sidr-left"
  class = "sidr-left-link"
  style = "float:left; position:static;margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;" > Left < /a>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'sidr_footer');

function put_up_lefter() {
  echo ' <
    a href = "#sidr-lefter"
  class = "sidr-lefter-link"
  style = "float:left; position:static;margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;" > Lefter < /a>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'sidr_footer');


function put_up_right() {
  echo ' <a href="#sidr-right" class="sidr-right-link" style="float:right; position:static;margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;">Right</a>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'sidr_footer');
```

```css
.sidr-left-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidr-lefter-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidr-right-link {
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<?php put_up_left()?>


<?php put_up_lefter()?>


<?php put_up_right()?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, already found the cure. Just needed to target my button class to Sidr button class.